# How to ignore a missing sheet in a rbind function?

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, rbind, openxlsx

I need help with troubleshooting this an error I keep getting.

I am trying to build a combined data.frame of 4 excel files containing various sheet.

However, because a sheet named "j" in the excel 'Mal' excel file is missing, the code wont run and it keeps returning

> ***Error: Sheet 'j' not found***

How do I fix the error please?

Thanks.

```
import_partnersubmissions_ALT <- function(){
  filelist <- list.files(path = "./Partner Submissions/", pattern = "*.xlsx")
  print(filelist)
  master <- data.frame()
  for(x in filelist){
    if(str_detect(x,"Bru")){
      print("Reading Bru...")
      master <- rbind(master,
                      read_partnerALT(x, "a"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "b"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "c"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "d"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "e"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "f"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "g")
      )
    }else if(str_detect(x,"Mal")){
      print("Reading Mal...")
      master <- rbind(master,
                      read_partnerALT(x, "h"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "i"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "j"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "k")
      )
    }else if(str_detect(x,"Sgp")){
      print("Reading Sgp...")
      master <- rbind(master,
                      read_partnerALT(x, "l"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "m"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "n"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "o")
      )
    }else if(str_detect(x,"Mld")){
      print("Reading Mld...")
      master <- rbind(master,
                      read_partnerALT(x, "p"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "q"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "r"),
                      read_partnerALT(x, "s")
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could try wrapping the `read_partnerALT` function into a `try` function.

Comment: Please could you explanation this further?

Comment: If you use `try(read_partnerALT(x, "j"))` it still throws an error, but you skript doesn't break. Alternatively, just remove `read_partnerALT(x, "j")`.

Comment: Yes, when I deleted the line, it throws up another error: “Error in match. names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names”

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*(Up front, you tagged this with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), so I assume you are using the `data.table` package. If not, then most of the below still applies, though you'll need to use `do.call(rbind, list(...))` in place of `rbindlist(list(...))`.)*</sup>

`rbind` is fine with `NULL` arguments, so wrap with `tryCatch`. However, writing this each time will get onerous, I suggest using `rbindlist`:

```r
master <- rbindlist(
  c(list(master), 
    lapply(c("h", "i", "j", "k"),
           function(S) tryCatch(read_partnerALT(x, S), error = function(e) NULL)))
)
```

I don't know the definition of `read_partnerALT`, so it's possible that that can be simplified a little, but the premise remains:

- iterate over your sheet names `c("h", "i", ...)`;
- pass that to an anon-func that makes the real call to `read_partnerALT` but wrapped in `tryCatch(.)`;
- if there is any kind of error with reading that sheet, it will instead return `NULL` for that sheet and silently continue

I'm not always a fan of doing things like this *silently*, so at the cost of brevity, we can make it a little more noteworthy:

```r
func <- function(S) {
  tryCatch(
    read_partnerALT(x, S),
    error = function(e) {
      warning(conditionMessage(e))
      NULL
    })
}
master <- rbindlist( c(list(master), lapply(c("h", "i", "j", "k"), func)) )
```

---

Demonstration:

```r
library(data.table)
MT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
```

Demonstrating the error condition:

```r
rbindlist(lapply(c("cyl", "gear", "quux"), function(S) MT[get(S) == 4,]))
# Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) : 
#   Object 'quux' not found amongst mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat and 6 more
```

Silent fix:

```r
rbindlist(lapply(c("cyl", "gear", "quux"), function(S) tryCatch(MT[get(S) == 4,], error = function(e) NULL)))
#       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear
#     <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4
#  2:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4
#  3:  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4
# ...
```

Warning fix:

```r
rbindlist(lapply(c("cyl", "gear", "quux"), function(S) tryCatch(MT[get(S) == 4,], error = function(e) {warning(conditionMessage(e)); NULL;})))
# Warning in value[[3L]](cond) :
#   Object 'quux' not found amongst mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat and 6 more
#       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear
#     <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4
#  2:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4
#  3:  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4
# ...
```